# how to write log in seq server

Tags: logging, serilog

I have a requirement like to log information in file or seq using serilog.
writing in file is mandatory and seq is optional.How to make it work the both rolling file and  seq by passing bool values.`ILogger logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                .Enrich.With(enricher)
                .WriteTo.Async(log => log.RollingFile(@"e:\" + "log-{Date}.txt",
                    outputTemplate:
                    "{Timestamp:yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss}  Application Name:{ApplicationName} Machine Name:{MachineName} {NewLine} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}"
                    ))
                .WriteTo.Seq(config.SeqUrl).Filter.ByIncludingOnly(con => config.IsLoggingSeq)
                .CreateLogger();`

Comment: I suggest starting with the [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events), try some code and if you have a specific problem, post a new question.

Comment: What you tried?